entypo css social icons displaying empty box
I'm trying to display social media icons using entypo.css. For some reason it is working in my development space but when I pushed to production I am getting empty boxes where the icons should be.  Example is in the footer here: https://econewsvt.org/
The code looks like:
<p id="socialMedia">
  <a class="icon-facebook-circled" href="http://www.facebook.com/econewsvt"></a>
  <a class="entypo-social c-twitter" href="https://twitter.com/ecoNEWS_VT"></a>
</p>

In the console I am seeing:
Access to font at 'https://www.econewsvt.org/font/Lora-Regular.ttf' from origin 'https://econewsvt.org' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
I tried updating my .htaccess with:
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://econewsvt.org"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

But am still getting the same issue. I'm not sure how to resolve this?

Look at least in the console before asking questions! Your font has been blocked by CORS police

thank you!  I tried adding Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://econewsvt.com" to the  .htaccess but am still getting the same issue.  How do I resolve it?

You can download this files in your machine & link it with your project, rather than using references directly.

@AbhayDedkawala thank you for the suggestion but I'm not sure what you mean by "link it with your project"? In the html or css?  Do you have an example?

If the site is from www - the problem will disappear https://www.econewsvt.org/
Configure the server to automatically redirect from one variant to another (from www.econewsvt.org to econewsvt.org or vice versa).
Or set:
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://econewsvt.org https://www.econewsvt.org"
</IfModule>


The rule was not in the .htaccess file to begin with and I still had the problem?

Somewhere my comment disappeared... I updated the answer.

update, there is a syntax error above.  The code that worked is: 
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://econewsvt.org"


Maybe ur adding header method is not working.
You should make sure that the mod_headers module is enabled in your Apache configuration. You can enable it using the code below
sudo a2enmod headers
sudo systemctl restart apache2

